# Custom tags for my very small cms (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, content-management-system

I'm developing a very small cms kind of thing. So far I have a page controller that lets you add pages. And there is a frontend controller. All calls are received by the frontend controller and respective page is displayed. Now I want to allow some custom tags while creating a page. I am using CKEditor and I want that while creating a page user gives a tag like `<!--cmsform_printform-->` and this tag will print printform method of cmsform controller.

For this I have created a controller cmsform that has a method printform. In my fronend controller I have created a method replace_tags that searches tags and then call respective controller and method.

But now I realized that my logic was false because I should not load a controller in another controller. I can't think of anyother logic. Please someone guide me or redirect me to a good codeigniter tutorial that explains this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried writing a helper instead? The functionality you describe sounds more like a helper method than a controller action.

CI manual in their site lists several excellent video tutorials, notably the ones published on NetTuts+. You might want to have a look, if you haven't already. Also, please do search CI forums. They contain plenty of information on pretty much any CI-related topic.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried helper functions. helper function helped me though but i think i should use helper function when i need to return some simple html.My situation is bit different. Admin will create a form from admin section. He will choose fields and lables and a form named XYZ will be created and CMS will generate a tag for that form. And when admin will place that tag while creating a page,that tag will be replaced with form. something like cforms in wordpress. want addon feature like wordpress or other big CMSes.

Comment: I see. I use Zend Framework on a daily basis and there's a neat function for calling controller actions anywhere, which I often use for, e.g., dynamic display of appropriate menu items across different controller actions. It's odd that CI doesn't offer such functionality, as it's indicated in this thread: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/55212/ :(